# How to write binary data from GZipStream after decompression to a file as binary data in C# .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, gzipstream

How to write binary data from GZipStream after decompression to a file as binary data in C# .NET 2.0:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("compressed_file.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

//Now how to save uncompressed binary data in "compressionStream" as a file ???
```

Comment: Here is example of how to do it ? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319438/How-to-Compress-Decompress-directories

Comment: OMG, I thought it will be 2-3 lines like File.Write(Stream) etc.

Answer (score 2):

its a two line solution, you just need to copy the compressionstream to a filestream.

```
using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream(sOutFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                  CopyStream(compressionStream, outFile);
```

Ok you need to make sure you are at the beginning of the compressionStream so adding

```
compressionStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

could be necessary.

EDIT:

Sorry so the implementation of copyTo should be something like this:

```
public void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize = 81920)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int read;
    while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

EDIT2:

the default bufferSize in the .Net4.5 implementation is defined as follows:

```
private const int _DefaultCopyBufferSize = 81920;
```

Full Source at [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,98ac7cf3acb04bb1,references)

Comment: I am using .NET 2.0, CopyTo is not available in .NET 2.0

Comment: What should be the bufferSize? The file/stream can be 5 MB to 50 MB in size